# How to stop a CSS image effect on mouse hover

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a wordpress theme and I'm trying to make a modification to the homepage.

One of the things I'm trying to change is the image hover effect, on hover the element shrinks which is not what I want, I need to it stay 100% width.

I'm new to CSS and HTML so I'm seeking help from the experts.

How can I stop the effect in CSS?

The site: http://testenvironment-wel.co.uk/

Comment: Which image? What code? Please post at least something that you might have tried along with details

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The Sectors - Clients and Projects images. I'm new to HTML and CSS and seeking help

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your css

```
.gridPhotoGallery__link.gridPhotoGallery__link-anim--zoomin:hover .gridPhotoGallery__img{transform: unset !important;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the effect is still active :(

Comment: can you send me image class

Comment: I think its this: .image-boxes.image-boxes--4 .image-boxes-title:after

Comment: .image-boxes.image-boxes--4:hover .image-boxes-img {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}  try this

Comment: I've added this but it seems like the effect is still there. any other ideas?

Comment: its not css effect the code i gives you is worked but your images are bad add better images and remove my code first because its effect on your image styles

Comment: change images and add some high resolution image

Comment: use this :  .image-boxes.image-boxes--4:hover .image-boxes-title:after{    width: 100%!important;}

Comment: I'm not sure how image quality would change the Hover Effect on an image. There is a thick RED element that sits under the Title (i.e. Sectors) when the mouse hovers over the image the red line gets slightly bigger. I need this red line bigger and sit behind the title (i.e. Sectors) with NO image hover effect. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: remove history and cache of your browser or open it in other pc in my pc its perfect no red line is gets bigger